# How to create a comparison expression using loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparison, string-comparison

I have following comparison expression:

```
return (!item['a'] || filter['a']) 
&& (!item['b'] || filter['b']) 
&& (!item['c'] || filter['c']);
```

But let's say I have a very long list of strings to be compared with `&&` for e.g.

```
var myList = ['a','b','c','d']
for(var i in myList) {
   //(!item[myList[i]] || filter[myList[i]]) How am I suppossed to && this for every iteration?

}
```

How am I suppossed to `&&` the expression for every iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use use `.every`:

```
return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].every(prop => !item[prop] || filter[prop]);
```